# Chrome Webstore Policy on HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, https, browser-extension, chrome-web-store

I couldn't find this explicitly mentioned in the docs, so, just to confirm, is it necessary for the apis my chrome-extension calls to use HTTPS?

Comment: There's no such requirement. Lots of extensions make http requests without any problems.

Comment: Firefox requires sensitive/private data e.g. user/pass etc to be sent on HTTPS only. I reckon Chrome should have a similar requirement as it is good practice anyway.